# Why is this WebElement not returning the full xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have several `WebElements` such that executing the following

```
List<WebElement> customers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Customers']/table/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println(customers.size());
```

would print **5**.

So then why does the following code

```
List<WebElement> customers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Customers']/table/tbody/tr"));

for (WebElement customer : customers) {
    if (customer.getText().equals("SQA")) {
        WebElement test = customer;
        System.out.println(test);
        break;
    }
}
```

print `xpath: //div[@id='Customers']/table/tbody/tr` and fail to actually include the *specific index of the path*? The above xpath is absolutely useless; I'm expecting the location of where **SQA** was found.

`xpath: //div[@id='Customers']/table/tbody/tr[4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it just prints the locator used to find the element. If you want the index, just change your code to

```
List<WebElement> customers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Customers']/table/tbody/tr"));
for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++)
{
    if (customers.get(i).getText().equals("SQA"))
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```